# Makefile equivalent behavior in Rakefile

Tags: ruby, makefile, rake

So I'm learning `ruby` at the moment and discovered `rake`. I like to learn new tools by implementing things I already know with them, so I try to convert a `Makefile` I have to `rake`.

Let's say it looks like this:

```
main: build/*.o
    clang -c $^ -o $@

build/%.o: src/%.c | build
    clang -c $< -o $@

build:
    mkdir build
```

What's *special* about this Makefile is:

1. Pattern matching with `%`
2. Order only dependency with `| build`

Is there some way to implement this logic using `rake` or do I have to use `ruby` itself? E.g.

```
task :default => "main"

file "main" => "build/%.o" do
  sh "clang -o 'main' ??"
end

file 'build/%.o' => "src/%.c" do # order only dependency on `build`
  sh "clang -c ?? ??"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something that rake is quite good at, and that is tragically underused:

```
task :default => "main"

# This assumes that your "main" is created by linking 
# all *.o files, each of which is the product of compiling a *.c file

# FileList[] creates a list of all *.c source files. The pathmap then
# changes the directory from /src/ to /out/ and the extension to .o

file "main" => FileList["src/**/*.c"].pathmap("%{^src,out}d/%n.o") do |t| 
   sh "ld #{t.sources.join(" ")} #{t.name}"
end

# This is the rule that says: if you need a 
# file out/bla.o, this will create it from /src/bla.c.    
rule /out\/.+.o/ => ->(target) { target.pathmap("%{^out,src}d/%n.c") } do |t|
  sh "cp #{t.source} #{t.name}"
end
```

Some notes:

- Rule names can be regex. I believe glob-style patterns are also possible, but find it easier to just always use regex
- If a rule's target already exists, and is newer than all its sources, it will not be executed again (like Make)
- pathmap and file tasks are Rake extensions for filenames. There's nothing similar for other entities such as database entries, but you can usually create them yourself